# Windows Forms DataGridView can't enter data in the last row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I was looking for a way to nicely enter data in the form of a matrix, and came
across the `DataGridView` control. I create and edit it dynamically, and so far it worked quite well. However, now I am having this weird problem: I can edit all of the cells normally, but when I come to the last row and try to enter data, I see my values written **over the cell values in the row above**.

Here is my code example:

```
            DataGridView table = new DataGridView();
            table.RowCount = 3;
            table.ColumnCount = 3;
            table.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            table.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            table.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3;++i)
                table.Columns[i].Width = 40;
            int width = 40 * 3;
            int height = 22 * 3;
            table.Width = width;
            table.Height = height;
            this.Controls.Add(table);
```

(*Note*: the purpose of this code was just to see what I can do with the control, it isn't supposed to do anything useful.)

Also, I have seen someone on a forum saying that I should disable users from adding rows, but when I do that, I have only two rows (instead of three like I specified), and that gray area where the third row should be.

**Edit**: another weird thing I've noticed is that, if I click **3 times** in the cell of the last row, I can edit it normally.

Comment: This is not the way in which you are supposed to use datagridview and that's why the weird behaviour (actually, I wouldn't expect even to have any cell). You are not expected to affect RowCount/ColumnCount directly; these variables are populated automatically as a reaction of the actions you should be doing (i.e., adding columns/rows/data). You should try to understand how to use the control and come here to ask specific questions. There are plently of online sample codes which will help you understand how to deal with this control. This question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

i Change your code, and it's work.
do this:

```
 DataGridView table = new DataGridView();

        table.ColumnCount = 3;
        table.Rows.Add(3);
        table.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        table.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        table.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            table.Columns[i].Width = 40;
        int width = 40 * 3;
        int height = 22 * 3;
        table.Width = width;
        table.Height = height;
        this.Controls.Add(table);
        table.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

first Add your columns and then add rows with table.Rows.Add(Number of rows), and at the end of code set allow users to add rows to false.